# UMEP Copernicus downloader ERA5 throwing Python Error

Tags: pyqgis, weather, copernicus

I am very new to using UMEP and I have installed it on QGIS 3.10 on MacOS and also on Windows but in both machines, I am running into the following error. I have set up my id/key API properly as I can see the files progress bar and API response but then after a while everytime, the following error is raised in both OS.

Can anyone point me to a fix?

I installed SuPy in my conda and my native environment and added my conda path to additional PATH as well just to be sure. Still, running into the same issue.

```
2020-08-06T16:56:21     WARNING    An error has occurred while executing Python code:
             
             
             NameError: name 'linecache' is not defined
             
             
             Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/UMEP/copernicus_data/WorkerDownload.py", line 41, in run
              sp.util.gen_forcing_era5(self.lat, self.lon, self.start_date, self.end_date, dir_save=str(self.folderPath))
              File "/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/supy/util/_era5.py", line 688, in gen_forcing_era5
              list_fn_sfc, concat_dim="time", combine="by_coords"
              File "/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 918, in open_mfdataset
              datasets = [open_(p, **open_kwargs) for p in paths]
              File "/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 918, in 
              datasets = [open_(p, **open_kwargs) for p in paths]
              File "/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 545, in open_dataset
              ds = maybe_decode_store(store)
              File "/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 465, in maybe_decode_store
              from dask.base import tokenize
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 743, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 13, in 
              from tlz import merge, groupby, curry, identity
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 743, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
             ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tlz'
             
             During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
             
             Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/UMEP/copernicus_data/WorkerDownload.py", line 45, in run
              errorstring = self.print_exception()
              File "/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/UMEP/copernicus_data/WorkerDownload.py", line 58, in print_exception
              linecache.checkcache(filename)
             NameError: name 'linecache' is not defined
             
             
             
             
             Python version: 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) 
             [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)]
             
             
             QGIS version: 3.10.8-A Coruña A Coruña, d09a4f2388
             
             
             Python Path:
             
             /Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/planet_explorer/extlibs/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/UMEP/SUEWSPrepare/Modules/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geos/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/python/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python37.zip/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/Users/adnanfiroze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/Users/adnanfiroze
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `dask` installation is not a complete one, which is required by `xarray`.
Install the complete `dask` as follows:

```
pip install dask[complete] --user
```

UMEP related issues should be submitted [here](https://github.com/UMEP-dev/UMEP/issues) to get prompt responses.

***disclaimer**: I'm the developer of SuPy.*